# Force less line spacing in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first) when I add to:

```
<ul class='list-inside list-disc px-0.5'>
    <li> <span class='italic font-semibold'>Billpay</span></li>
    <li> <span class='italic font-semibold'>Check</span></li>
    <li> <span class='italic font-semibold'>EFT</span></li>
    </ul>
```

<kbd>text-xl</kbd>:

```
<ul class='list-inside list-disc px-0.5'>
    <li><span class='text-xl'></span> <span class='italic font-semibold'>Billpay</span></li>
    <li><span class='text-xl'></span> <span class='italic font-semibold'>Check</span></li>
    <li><span class='text-xl'></span> <span class='italic font-semibold'>EFT</span></li>
    </ul>
```

The spacing on the lines increase from:

[image: before, desired spacing]

to:

[image: after, extra spacing]

How can I keep the original spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Tailwind applies a different line height for each text size (see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size). For normal text the line height is 1.5rem, and for `text-xl` it's 1.75rem. To tighten up your lines, you could try applying the utility classes `text-xl leading-normal` (or `text-xl leading-snug`, if it's still too tall).